# R Plot muliptle lines with dates

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to create a line plot in R. For each 'RuleID' in my data frame I want to plot the 'ErrorCount' at each 'ProcessorTimeStamp'

```
DQ_Counts= data.frame(RuleID=c(1,2,1,2),
                  ProcessorTimeStamp=as.Date(c('2016-08-04','2016-08-04','2016-08-08','2016-08-08')),
                  ErrorCount=c(6,8,3,4))

#   RuleID ProcessorTimeStamp ErrorCount
# 1      1         2016-08-04          6
# 2      2         2016-08-04          8
# 3      1         2016-08-08          3
# 4      2         2016-08-08          4
```

This is a plot I found online that I would like the end result to look like all though I am obviously not talking about trees.  The code for this plot is here [Code for Tree Growth Plot](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/line.html) but I don't understand it well enough to make it work for me.
[image]

For my plot 'ProcessTimeStamp' would be my x and 'ErrorCount' would by my y.  Each line would represent a different 'RuleID'.
One thing to note is that I have 'ErrorCounts' ranging from 0 to over 3 million (this is why I need to report on them to get them fixed!).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the easiest way to get a basic plot like the one above with your data

```
lattice::xyplot(ErrorCount~ProcessorTimeStamp, DQ_Counts, 
    groups=RuleID, auto.key=T, type="l")
```

Which returns

[image]

or you could use ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DQ_Counts, aes(ProcessorTimeStamp, ErrorCount, color=factor(RuleID))) + geom_line()
```

to get

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have been using only base R for my plots but it looks like it is time to start something new.  Which library is more popular/better/etc, lattice or ggplot?  Thanks again

Comment: @JRDew Definitely ggplot2.

Comment: Great, I will try ggplot2 this afternoon and update here.  One thing I did notice is that the above plot has every day on the x line, not just the dates from 'ProcessTimeStamp'.  My dates could be days, weeks, or months apart so I will need to mess with that a little. Thanks.

Comment: I had to add aes(group=RuleID) to the geom_line.  So my final line looks like this:  ggplot(DQ_Counts, aes(ProcessorTimeStamp, ErrorCount, color=factor(RuleID))) + geom_line(aes(group=RuleID))  I am sure this is something that is different between my sample data above and the actual data in my data frame.